# Can't access JQuery or Foundation functions from separate file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

Basically, the problem is this: 
I have some code that adds an event listener to each button on a page. If a login cookie is not set, then the code triggers a Foundation modal using a Foundation-provided function. If the cookie IS set and the user is logged in, then the user is directed to their desired page.

The problem is, I can't seem to fire the foundation code from my file, even though the foundation files are being included in the same page; everything else is working. What's going on? Here's the code:

```
// Anonymous function wrapper
(function () {
    // getting an array of all buttons on the page, based on a button class
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

    // main function to run after ternary operator check (found at bottom)
    function run () {
        // cookieCheck() returns true/false depending on whether 
        // the cookie is set
        var cookie = cookieCheck(),
            modal = document.getElementById('loginModal'),
            i, j = button.length;

        // looping through each button, applying an even listener
        for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
            (function (i) {
                button[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    var link = e.target.getAttribute('target');
                    if (cookie === false) {
                        // Firing foundation function. PROBLEM IS HERE!!!
                        $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
                    } else {
                        // if cookie is set, direct user to proper page
                        e.target.href = link;
                    }
                }, false);
            }(i));
        }
    }

    // if buttons exist on the page, the function runs.
    // this prevents errors being thrown in the console on pages with no buttons
    button ? run() : false;
}());
```

HTML (I didn't write this part, or the PHP, I just did the javascript here):

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

    <div id="loginModal" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal>
        <?php gravity_form( 2, true, true, false, '', false ); ?>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>

    <script>
        (function($) {
            $(document).foundation();
        })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <!-- This is the script in question /-->
    <script src="/static/themes/RWv3/js/custom.js"></script>
    <?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
        <script src="/static/themes/RWv3/js/vendor/main.js"></script>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

Why is this happening?

thanks

Comment: Can you post the HTML where the scripts are being included?

Comment: Is the file with the funcion included before the file which uses the function?

Comment: @MisterDev ,  the file is being included below the others that provide the function. But do keep in mind this a crazy wordpress site, (I hate wordpress), so maybe that is a factor.

Comment: @Aweary sure, one sec

Comment: If you add `console.log($(document).foundation)` at the top of your function call, does it log out `undefined` or what?

Comment: @Aweary an error is fired, claiming that the contents of that line are not a function, meaning, I assume, that the interpreter isn't recognizing the jQuery stuff.